# Set Online meeting in Teams

Tags: c#, asp.net, exchangewebservices, microsoft-teams

I have been using Exchange WebServices (EWS) for some time now, in `Asp.net C #`, to add events in the calendars of Office365 users at my work.
I now needed those same events to appear at Microsoft Teams, with the possibility of going on videoconference.
Events appear but that possibility is not present.

One of the properties of "`appointments`" is "`isOnlineMeeting`". I tried to add it, making it `true`, but it always returns an error saying "Set action is invalid for property.".

In the online searches I have done, I have found that this is a read-only property.

So, is there any chance that I can "force" this property?

I have already configured my Exchange so that, in Outlook online when we do a new event, this is always by videoconference.

Some help?

Thank you!

**UPDATE**:
By the way, the code that I'm using is:

```
try {
        ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService (ExchangeVersion.Exchange2013_SP1, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById ("GMT Standard Time"));
            service.Url = new Uri ("https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx");

            string User = "a@a.net";
            string Password = "AAA";

            service.Credentials = new NetworkCredential (User, Password);

            Appointment appointment = new Appointment (service);

            appointment.Subject = "Experiment";

            appointment.Location = "Videoconference";

            string dataStart = "10-02-2021 19:00:00.000";
            string dataEnd = "10-02-2021 20:00:00.000";
            appointment.Start = DateTime.Parse (dataStart);
            appointment.End = DateTime.Parse (dataEnd);

            appointment.Body = "<strong>Ignore! Just a test</strong>";

            appointment.IsOnlineMeeting = true;

            appointment.RequiredAttendees.Add ("b@a.net");

            appointment.Save (SendInvitationsMode.SendOnlyToAll);

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            
        }
```

Comment: [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.appointment.isonlinemeeting?view=exchange-ews-api) talks that you can get/set the value for it. Are you talking about it?

Comment: @user3330412: I agree with dev answer. You can set "isOnlineMeeting" property. Please try to use latest SDK to see the required changes.

Comment: I'm sorry I took so long to answer ...
I have installed version 2.2 of the EWS.
Even so, I am not allowed to change the value of the property.
I get the same error message.

If I comment the line of code, there is no problem and the event is scheduled. It just doesn't appear in Microsoft Teams, the button to participate in the video conference.

If you schedule the event from Oulook online, this button appears. Only programmatically with EWS does not appear ...

Thank you!

Comment: Could you please try with this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/calendar-post-events?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example-2-create-and-enable-an-event-as-an-online-meeting) by using Graph API.

By using Graph API we can set "isOnlineMeeting" property to  true, and "onlineMeetingProvider" property to  "teamsForBusiness".

Answer (score 0):

**Posting the Answer for better knowledge**

**Copying from comments**

Could you please try with this document by using Graph API. By using Graph API we can set "isOnlineMeeting" property to true, and "onlineMeetingProvider" property to "teamsForBusiness".